# How to set index of TabBarView?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to mount `BottomNavigationBar` to `TabBarView`. How to set the `index` of `TabBarView` so I can display 2nd item (search page)? should I use `Ontap` and `switch case`? still how to set the index?

```
body: SafeArea(
      // child: (pages[currentIndex1]),
      child: TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Home(),
          Search(),
        ].toList(),
        // controller: ,
      ),
    ),

    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: currentIndex1,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
     
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      showSelectedLabels: false,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: 'Search',
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        
      ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to provide `TabController` on `TabBarView`, then you can switch tabItems using this controller.

you can check this example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("home"),
    );
  }
}

class Search extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("Search"),
    );
  }
}

class NavTest extends StatefulWidget {
  NavTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NavTestState createState() => _NavTestState();
}

class _NavTestState extends State<NavTest> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final widgets = [
    Home(),
    Search(),
  ];
  int currentIndex1 = 0;

  late TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(length: widgets.length, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        // child: (pages[currentIndex1]),
        child: TabBarView(
          children: widgets,
          controller: controller,
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex1,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: 'Search',
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (value) {
          setState(() {
            // currentIndex1 = value;
            controller.index = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```